# Unable to convert my scala object with ArrayBuffer to JSON

Tags: json, scala

My Scala Object

```
class Product(@BeanProperty var productName: String,
    @BeanProperty var source: String,
    @BeanProperty var category: String,
    @BeanProperty var comments: ArrayBuffer[String]) {

}
```

Using Jackson API

```
 val p = new Product("","","",list with 1000 values) 
 var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper
    println(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(p))
```

Output :

```
"productName":"Apple iPhone 6","source":"dump_gsm_arena","category":"Mobile","comments":**{"empty":false,"traversableAgain":true}**}
```

Got same result using Play and JsonLift Api

Comment: The question is not very clear. Please explain what you are expecting to see and what is the issue that you are seeing clearly .